# Is there a software, making questions with given data as answer to it?

Tags: programming, data-analysis, data, artificial-intelligence, research

Is there a software, making questions with given data as answer to it? I have a math project; I am writing a review of the "search of solution set of quintic equations". I have taken primary sources and am identifying possible questions, with given sentence in source as answer.

Below I have given examples, I have extracted sentences (typed after "Found data") from Niels Henrik
Abel's "Memoir on algebraic equations, in which is demonstrated the im-
possibility of solving the general equation of the fifth degree" (1824), and have typed possible questions (typed after "Search") which can be formed, with sentences in found data as answer to them.

Is there a sofware which can frame questions with each sentence in a book or paper as answer to those questions?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did some work on code from Michael Heilmann and Noah H. Smith which attempts to tackle this issue (question generation from text), and can be used as starting point for further research:

https://github.com/kutschkem/SmithHeilmann_fork/tree/master/SmithHeilmann

This is from around 2010, so 10 years old. There has probably been more research since then, maybe this can help to get started.